# Python Find the sum in a string NO IMPORTS

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know the question might not seem hard but it is a tricky one, let me explain.

> **Input** 
> *Bla bla this is 45 text 10.5 bla bla -1 this is tricky* 
> **Output**
> *54.5* 
> **Explanation** 
> *45 + 10.5 -1 = 54.5*

I can already sum digits or numbers from a string but I don't know how to seperate the float numbers and negative ones like 10.5 and -1.
Below is the code I have now which only sums the ints not floats or negative numbers:

```
def findSum(text):
string = "0"
Sum = 0

for char in text:
     if (char.isnumeric()) :
        string += char
        nums = char.split('.')
     else:
         Sum += float(string)
         string = "0"
return Sum + float(string)

 text = "sqdkl 45 qsd 10.5 qsdaf -1"
 print(findSum(text))
```

**ALSO NO IMPORTS**

Comment: Try using `re` library(RegEx). You can easily create a matching condition using `re.compile()` and use `re.findall()` to search for numbers. Reference: [RegEx](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp). I am not very familiar with regex, but I think the sequence  `-*\d+` might work

Comment: I am not allowed to use imports

Comment: This looks like an student exercise, which if i am not mistaken, the community shall not provide a direct solution. Especially the **no imports** (even from the standard library) restriction makes this question a good candidate for being an school exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions:

```
import re

inpt = "Bla bla this is 45 text 10.5 bla bla -1 this is tricky"

result = 0

matches = re.findall("[-]*[0-9.]+", inpt)

for match in matches:
    result += float(match)
    
result # 54.5
```

Comment: Not allowed to use imports such as regex

Answer (score 0):

Check if each "word" is a positive or negative number and add to `total`:

```
def findSum(text):
    total = 0
    for word in text.split():
        if word[0]=="-" and word[1:].count(".")<=1 and word[1:].replace(".", "").isnumeric():
            total += float(word)
        elif word.count(".")<=1 and word.replace(".", "").isnumeric():
            total += float(word)
    return total

>>> findSum("Bla bla this is 45 text 10.5 bla bla -1 this is tricky")
54.5
```

Alternatively, try to add every "word" and ignore exceptions:

```
def findSum(text):
    total = 0
    for word in text.split():
        try:
            total += float(word)
        except ValueError:
            continue
    return total
```

Comment: Thank you it works on all texts but this one                                                                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen bas popularised in the 1960 with tm

Comment: It also wouldn't work for numbers with "," in the middle like 1,300,000. You can have an extra line to replace all punctuation like ";" "," "?" etc. from numbers

Answer (score 0):

Eliminated every alphabetical characters using `str.replace`, split the string and cast to `float`.

The list of the alphabetical characters can be obtained using `string.ascii_letters`. Since you cannot use imports, *copy-paste* its output in your code (`print(string.ascii_letters)`).

```
text = "sqdkl 45 qsd 10.5 qsdaf -1"
import string # it can be removed and introduce an own list

chars_to_be_removed = string.ascii_letters + ',:;' # depends on the data

for char in chars_to_be_removed:
    text = text.replace(char, '')

sum_ = sum(float(n.strip()) for n in text.split(' ') if n != '')
print(sum_)
```

**EDIT**: stronger approach

Since no rules is given concerning the allowed characters in string, repetitions of `.` or '-' (are parts of both language and arithmetical expressions!), here a more robust implementation. It is based on `groupby` function of the `itertools`-build-in package. It can handle string such as

`"sqdkl 45 qsd 10.5 qsd....af -1 bih-ds----a10"`.

It uses an allowed set of characters instead of set of characters to be removed.

```
import itertools as it

text = "sqdkl 45 qsd 10.5 qsd....af -1 bih-ds----a"

import string # it can be removed and introduce an own list
allowed_chars = string.digits+'-.'

sum = 0
for match, chars in it.groupby(text, lambda s: s in allowed_chars):
    if match:
        num = ''.join(chars)
        # group with 1 element
        if '.' == num or '-' == num:
            continue
        # group with more elements
        if num.count('-') > 1 or num.count('.') > 1:
            continue
        #print(num)
        sum += float(''.join(num))
print(sum)
```

Comment: I see but I am not allowed to use imports

Comment: Hi! just follow remarks at the beginning of the program: Run `print(string.ascii_letters)` or `print(string.digits)` , copy-paste the output and eliminate the `imports string` and replace `string.digits` or `string.ascii_letters`  with that output. Sorry for the confusion, just too lazy!